# While I'm fetching the user when I refresh the page, get me out of the protected route, how can I prevent that? Redux MERN

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a protected route that only a logged in user can access.

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  const { user } = useSelector(state => state.auth);

  return user ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='/' />;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

I load the user from the backend and it takes a split second and since the protected route redirects to '/' when I refresh the protected page it takes me back to '/' because I don't have a user in a split second. I load user in App.js:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadUser());
  }, []);
```

I also have a problem while fetching the user, I get a login in a split second when I refresh the page, how can I prevent that?

```
<Navbar.Collapse id='basic-navbar-nav'>
          {user ? (
            <div className='ms-auto d-flex align-items-center'>
              <Nav.Link as={Link} to='/create-post'>
                Create Post
              </Nav.Link>
              <div>
                <Image
                  className='user-img'
                  fluid
                  src={user?.avatar.url}
                ></Image>
              </div>
              <NavDropdown title={user.username} id='username'>
                <LinkContainer to={`/profile/${user._id}`}>
                  <NavDropdown.Item>Profile</NavDropdown.Item>
                </LinkContainer>
                <NavDropdown.Item onClick={logoutHandler}>
                  Logout
                </NavDropdown.Item>
              </NavDropdown>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <Nav className='ms-auto'>
              <Nav.Link as={Link} to='/login'>
                Log In
              </Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link as={Link} to='/register'>
                Sign Up
              </Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
          )}
        </Navbar.Collapse>
```

Comment: The general idea is that you delay the route rendering until the auth status of the user has been determined. Otherwise you'll always have a flickering state because "you need to login" is shown until the backend has verified the logged in user. A flag in the redux state works well for this, it's initialized as `false` when the app loads, and only set to true once you know for sure wether the user needs to go to the login page or may see a protected route.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is that you delay the route rendering until the auth status of the user has been determined. Otherwise you'll always have a flickering state because "you need to login" is shown until the backend has verified the logged in user. A flag in the redux state works well for this, it's initialized as `false` when the app loads, and only set to `true` once you know for sure wether the user needs to go to the login page or may see a protected route. While the auth status is figured out, you can show a loading indicator, or some kind of blank page.

Main takeaway: model a third state "auth status pending" besides the already existing "logged in" and "logged out" states.